# Abrir Poup-Up - Ajuda

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte HTML, porém tudo na mesma página
id **entrada** é onde ele pega meu campo de entrada do endereço digitado
**chegada** é onde ele pega o endereço final
**resultado** é o calculo:

```
    <div id="entrada"></div>
    <div id="chegada"></div>
    <div id="Resultado"></div>

<input type="submit" class="btn-green" id="btnCalcular" onclick="calcular();" value="Calcular" />
```

Tenho essa function para calcular meus input text:

```
<script language= "javascript">
function calcular(){
            var litros = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtKM').value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtKML').value);
            var valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtPL').value) * litros;
            document.getElementById('Resultado').innerHTML = "<br><b>Gasto total: R$ </b>" + valor;
            var txtentrada = document.getElementById('txtEnderecoPartida').value;
            document.getElementById('entrada').innerHTML = "<br><b>Endereço de Partida:</b><br>" + txtentrada;
            var txtchegada = document.getElementById('txtEnderecoChegada').value;
            document.getElementById('chegada').innerHTML = "<br><b>Endereço de Chegada:</b><br>" + txtchegada;
        }
</script>
```

Agora, oque eu queria saber é:
Como faço pra na hora de clicar no botão ele possa abrir em uma outra página (poup-up), ja tentei com windows.open mas não abre, ja que meu onclick está chamando essa função na mesma página pra calcular.

EDIT:
Tenho esse HTML:

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="window.open('index.php', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=900, HEIGHT=500');">
```

Queria puxar a informação do **resultado** para uma nova página;

Comment: Para o pop-up precisa passar um parametro adicional, tentou?:
`window.open ('popup.html', 'popup')`

Comment: Nota que o navegador bloqueia o pop, precisa liberar a primeira vez.

Comment: E para enviar o resultado para a nova página no pop-up, pode passar via get ou post. via get seria simples: `window.open ('index.php?par1=2&par2=3', 'popup')`

Comment: Posta o html todo se der, ta meio confuso. Onde estão este elementos com id **txtKM** e **txtPL**?

Comment: Leandro, esse seria meus inputs com os respectivos ids para pegar a distância em km, consumo do combustível em km e preço do combustível para no fim clicar no botão calcular e obter o resultado, sendo assim ao clicar ele mostra na página e estava quenrendo abrir em uma nova janela (pou-up).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode enviar o valor para a nova janela *popup* via POST, criando um `form` dinâmico.

Link para abrir a *popup*:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="novaJanela()">Abrir janela</a>
```

Função:

```
function novaJanela(){

   // seleciono o form para ver se ele existe
   var popupform = document.body.querySelector("#popupform");

   // se ele existe, excluo do DOM
   if(popupform) popupform.outerHTML = '';

   // pego o texto na div #Resultado
   var res = document.getElementById("Resultado").textContent;

   var f = document.createElement("form"); // crio o form
   f.method = "post"; // adiciono método post
   f.target = "Pagina"; // defino o alvo para a popup
   f.action = "index.php"; // defino o action para o index.php da popup
   f.id = "popupform"; // defino uma id ao form
   f.style.cssText = "display: none;"; // escondo o form para que funcione em background

   var i = document.createElement("input"); // crio o input do form que levará o valor
   i.value = res; // adiciono o valor ao input
   i.name = "resultado"; // dou um nome ao input que será capturado pelo PHP
   f.appendChild(i); // adiciono o input ao form

   document.body.appendChild(f); // adiciono o form ao DOM

   // abro a popup
   window.open('index.php', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=900, HEIGHT=500');

   f.submit(); // submeto o form à popup
}
```

Na *popup* `index.php` você pega o valor usando POST:

```
<?php
$resultado = $_POST['resultado'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte: coloque no `href` do link `<a>`:

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

Isso irá impedir ação de redirecionamento do link. E coloque no `onclick` uma função para abrir uma nova janela:

```
onclick="novaJanela()"
```

O `<a>` ficará assim:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="novaJanela()">Abrir janela</a>
```

Feito isso, adicione a função `novaJanela()` no script:

```
function novaJanela(){

   var res = document.getElementById("Resultado").innerHTML;

   window.open('index.php?resultado='+res, 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=900, HEIGHT=500');

}
```

A variável `var res` irá armazenar o conteúdo da `div Resultado` e enviar como parâmetro "*resultado*" para a *popup*:

```
window.open('index.php?resultado='+res,...
```

Na *popup* `index.php` você pega o valor usando GET:

```
<?php
$resultado = $_GET['resultado'];
?>
```

> Este modo de abrir a *popup* não será bloqueado pelo navegador porque
>   foi resultado de interação do usuário através de um clique.

Comment: Até ai tudo bem, mas, pelo que entendi ele pega o valor gerado em resultado e mostra no link, por exemplo:
 meusite/index.php?resultado=<b>Gasto%20total:%20R$%20</b>19.764705882352942

Gostaria que me mostrar esse valor em uma nova página e não la no link, mas ja me deu uma ideia de como fazer outras coisas com isto.

Comment: Use textContent em vez de innerHTML

Comment: Entendi. Vc não quer que o valor apareça na URL?

Comment: Não, mas ajuda tbm. Mas, gostaria de puxar o valor informado da minha div resultado, para outra pagina, assim que clicado no botão, abrir uma página ou poup-up

PS: agora que eu vi oque postou acima, vou ver!

Comment: Nem percebi uma coisa: vc quer fazer isso usando PHP?

Comment: Então, olha essa imagem:
http://www.liguetaxi.com.br/Capturar.PNG

<div id="entrada"></div>
    <div id="chegada"></div>
    <div id="Resultado"></div>

Essas 3 divs, são as que aparecem apó eu clicar em Calcular. Sendo assim gostaria que pudesse aparecer em outra página. Desculpa o mal entendimento

Comment: Eu entendi que vc quer jogar o valor do resultado para outra página. Mas vc tem controle do código da outra página?

Comment: então, ai que está o problema. Eu não sei por onde começar, mas você teria alguma página de exemplo pra fazer algo simular, seja em php ou javascript?

Eu no caso teria que criar a outra página para que pudesse puxar essa informação?
o Código em si, está na mesma página.